# npm EACCES on docker-compose but not with docker with

Tags: php, node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have created a Docker Image to build a PHP server stack with a custom front running by a node container to run the [Bud](https://bud.js.org/) framework.

Everything was okay and functionnal until I upgrade the node packages. Now, I am getting an error while I want to run my stack with docker-compose: the node container exited with code 1.

Here my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  traefik:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:2.8
    container_name: val-traefik
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./docker/images/traefik/certs:/etc/certs
      - ./docker/images/traefik/config/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./docker/images/traefik/config/traefik-dynamic.toml:/traefik-dynamic.toml
      - ./docker/data/logs/traefik:/var/log
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal
      - traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.val.lan`)
      - traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure
    networks:
      - web

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23.3-alpine
    container_name: val-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./web:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/images/nginx/config/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./docker/data/logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.val-nginx.rule=Host(`val.lan`)
      - traefik.http.routers.val-nginx.tls=true
    links:
      - php:php-fpm
    networks:
      - web
      - private-val

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/images/Dockerfile
      target: php_fpm
    container_name: val-php
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/images/php-fpm/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./docker/images/php-fpm/config/zzz-global.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz-global.conf
      - ./docker/data/logs/php-fpm:/var/www/logs
      - ./i18n/plugins:/var/www/html/web/app/languages/plugins
      - ./i18n/wpml:/var/www/html/web/app/languages/wpml
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - private-val

  node-dev:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/images/Dockerfile
      target: theme_builder
    container_name: val-node
    volumes:
      - ./web/app/themes/val:/var/www/html
    links:
      - nginx:nginx
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.val-node.rule=Host(`val-dev.lan`)
      - traefik.http.routers.val-node.tls=true
      - traefik.http.services.val-node.loadbalancer.server.port=443
    networks:
      - web
      - private-val

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: val-db
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./docker/images/mysql/config:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ./docker/images/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - private-val

  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.8.1
    container_name: val-adminer
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.val-adminer.rule=Host(`val-adminer.lan`)
      - traefik.http.routers.val-adminer.tls=true
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - web
      - private-val

networks:
  web:
    external: true
  private-val:
    driver: bridge
```

And the correspondig `Dockerfile` used by `php` and `node`:

```
##############################
#    THEME ASSETS BUILDER    #
##############################

FROM node:16-alpine AS theme_builder

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY web/app/themes/val ./

RUN npm install

# Expose port 3000 and start node server
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:www"]

#################
#    PHP-FPM    #
#################

FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine AS php_fpm

# Install required packages
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client msmtp perl wget procps shadow libzip libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp freetype icu mariadb-connector-c

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-essentials \
    icu-dev icu-libs zlib-dev g++ make automake autoconf libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev libwebp-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev curl-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    docker-php-ext-install curl && \
    apk del build-essentials && rm -rf /usr/src/php*

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install PHP Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=2.5.4

# Remove Cache
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Add UID '1001' to www-data
RUN usermod -u 1001 www-data

COPY composer.json composer.lock .env auth.json ./
RUN composer install

COPY wp-cli.yml ./
COPY config ./config
COPY web ./web
COPY patches ./patches
COPY fixtures ./fixtures
COPY bin/script ./script

# Translations
COPY i18n ./web/app/languages

# Fixing permissions for www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data .

# Starting container with www-data user
USER www-data

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

When I starting all the stack with `docker-compose up`, I'm getting this error:

```
val-node        |
val-node        | > dev:www
val-node        | > bud dev --proxy https://val.lan/
val-node        |
val-node        |
val-node        |
val-node        |  Error
val-node        |
val-node        | ✘ EACCES: permission denied, stat
val-node        | '/root/.cache/bud-nodejs/qFEqpxH3V2CP2sUw+CzZcmFvjG0=/checksum.yml'
val-node        |
val-node        | ☰ Stack trace
val-node        |
val-node exited with code 1
```

but all the others containers works perfectly.

I don't know why this not working anymore since it worked just before I upgraded the node packages and still don't understand why it can't access to the `root` directory since I never set the `USER` directive in my `node-dev` custom image.

Any idea to solve this problem?